# How do I cache files within a function app?

Tags: python, azure, caching, azure-function-app

I am trying to temporarily store files within a function app. The function is triggered by an http request which contains a file name. I first check if the file is within the function app storage and if not, I write it into the storage.

**Like this:**

```
    if local_path.exists():
        file = json.loads(local_path.read_text('utf-8'))
    else:
        s = AzureStorageBlob(account_name=account_name, container=container, 
                          file_path=file_path, blob_contents_only=True, 
                          mi_client_id=mi_client_id, account_key=account_key)
        local_path.write_bytes(s.read_azure_blob())
        file = json.loads((s.read_azure_blob()).decode('utf-8'))
```

**This is how I get the local path**

```
    root = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
    
    file_name = pathlib.Path(file_path).name
    local_path = root.joinpath('file_directory').joinpath(file_name)
```

If I upload the files when deploying the function app everything works as expected and I read the files from the function app storage. But if I try to save or cache a file, it breaks and gives me this error `Error: [Errno 30] Read-only file system:`

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: May ways to do this, of course, but take a look a the shelve library -- I think it would meet your needs fine and is easy to implement; https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#

Comment: Ok I will try it. I am hesitant to use dictionary-like databases due to efficiency concerns but I will give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

So after a year I discovered that Azure function apps can utilize the python os module to save files which will persist throughout calls to the function app. No need to implement any sort of caching logic. Simply use os.write() and it will work just fine.

I did have to implement a function to clear the cache after a certain period of time but that was a much better alternative to the verbose code I had previously.